# regex detect any string with no extension at the end

Tags: php, regex

there is a string which its ending would be like this:

```
test/15-test
```

How to exclude those strings that have extension at the end. like this one:

```
test/15-test.jpg
```

and only select one's with no extension at the end.

this is my pattern but it is not working

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\/-]+\/[0-9]+-*(?!(\.(\w)).)$
```

and also string after number can contain UTF-8 characters.
for example:

```
test/14-تست
```

Comment: Try `(?!\.[A-Za-z]+$).+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
/[\p{L}\p{N}\/-]+\/[0-9]+-[\p{L}\p{N}_]+$/u
```

OR

```
/[\p{L}\p{N}\/-]+\/[0-9]+-[^.]+$/u
```

Comment: this doesn't accept UTF-8 characters at the end. for example test/14-تست does not work.

Comment: Hmm you didn't write about UTF-8 input in question. It is updated now and should work for those inputs also.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following patterns:

- `^(?i)([^\/]+\/[0-9a-z-]+(?!\.[a-z]+)$)`
- `^(?i)([^\/]+\/[^.]+(?!\.[a-z]+)$)` (As per your update in your question)